# How important is os-variant for kvm configuration?

Tags: security, performance, kvm, stability

When searching the internet one can always read that specifying `os-variant` is important so KVM can optimize the guest system. Nowhere did I find an article, manual or documentation stating how important this option is in kind of performance, stability and security. The option is optional and until now I did not notice an impact on the 3 criteria I mentioned.

Is there a specific measurable impact with this option or can one say this option is to please ones conscience?